# ImageMagick DisplayImages() for Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, image, imagemagick

The ImageMagick library has a function DisplayImages which can be called to bring up a window containing an image.  I want to use this to check that things are being done as I intend.  This function works in Linux, but does not appear to work in Windows.  Is there some other function that provides this capability?